# Simple threading in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I need to implement threading in Django. I require three simple APIs:

1. /work?process=data1&jobid=1&jobtype=nonasync
2. /status
3. /kill?jobid=1

The API descriptions are:

1. The `work` api will take a `process` and spawn a thread that processes it. For now, we can assume it to be a simple `sleep(10)` method. It will name the thread as `jobid-1`. The thread should be retrievable by this name. A new thread cannot be created if a jobid already exists. The `jobtype` could be `async` i.e, api call will immediately return `http status code 200` after spawning a thread. Or it could be `nonasync` such that the api waits for the server to complete the thread and return result.
2. `status` api should just show the statues of each running processes.
3. `kill` api should kill a process based on `jobid`. `status` api should not show this job any longer.

Here is my Django code:

```
processList = []


class Processes(threading.Thread):
""" The work api can instantiate a process object and monitor it completion"""

    threadBeginTime = time.time()

    def __init__(self, timeout, threadName, jobType):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.totalWaitTime = timeout
        self.threadName = threadName
        self.jobType = jobtype

    def beginThread(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.execution,
            name = self.threadName)
        self.thread.start()

    def execution(self):
        time.sleep(self.totalWaitTime)

    def calculatePercentDone(self):
        """Gets the current percent done for the thread."""
        temp = time.time()
        secondsDone = float(temp - self.threadBeginTime)
        percentDone = float((secondsDone) * 100 / self.totalWaitTime)
        return (secondsDone, percentDone)

    def killThread(self):
        pass
        # time.sleep(self.totalWaitTime)

def work(request):
    """ Django process initiation view """
    data = {}
    timeout = int(request.REQUEST.get('process'))
    jobid = int(request.REQUEST.get('jobid'))
    jobtype = int(request.REQUEST.get('jobtype'))
    myProcess = Processes(timeout, jobid, jobtype)
    myProcess.beginThread()
    processList.append(myProcess)
    return render_to_response('work.html',{'data':data}, RequestContext(request))


def status(request):
    """ Django process status view """
    data = {}
    for p in processList:
        print p.threadName, p.calculatePercentDone()

    return render_to_response('server-status.html',{'data':data}, RequestContext(request))


def kill(request):
    """ Django process kill view """
    data = {}
    jobid = int(request.REQUEST.get('jobid'))
    # find jobid in processList and kill it
    return render_to_response('server-status.html',{'data':data}, RequestContext(request))
```

There are several implementation issues in the above code. The thread spawning is not done in a proper way. I am not able to retrieve the processes status in `status` function. Also, the kill function is still implemented as I could not grab thread from its job id. Need help refactoring.

**Update**: I am doing this example for learning purposes, not for writing production code. Hence will not favour any off-the-shelf queueing libraries. The objective here is to understand how a multithreading works in conjunction with a web framework and what edge cases are there to be dealt.

Comment: Trying to implement this yourself is a recipe for disaster. Use the tried-and-tested existing solution, Celery.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am not looking for a production code here. More like a conceptual learning on threading and Django. Need to use bare Threading library to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

As @Daniel Roseman mentioned above -- doing threading INSIDE of a Django request / response cycle is a very bad idea for many reasons.

What you're actually looking for here is task queueing.

There are a few libraries out there which make this sort of thing fairly simple -- I'll list them below in order of ease-of-use (the simplest ones are listed first):

- Django-RQ (https://github.com/ui/django-rq) -- A very awesome, simple API that uses Redis to handle queueing and asynchronous tasks.
- Celery (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) -- A very powerful, flexible, and large projects which handles queuing and supports many different technologies for backends. I'd recommend this for large projects, but for everything else I'd use RQ as it's quite a bit simpler.

Just my two cents.

Comment: rdegges As I mentioned in the comment above, its important for me to understand the inner winding of how Threading works. Ofcourse your suggestions are great for writing production ready code and to skip reinventing the wheel. But the objective here is learning.